# Modifying SQL XML column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I have an XML column in one of my table. For example I have an Employee table with following fields:

`Name (varhcar) | Address (XML)`

The Address field is having values like

```
<Address>
<Street></Street>
<City></City>
</Address>
```

I have some n number of rows already in the table.
Now I want to insert a new node - Country to all the rows in tha table. With default:

```
<Country>IND</Country>.
```

How can I write the query for this. I want all the existing data to be as it is with adding the country node to all the Address column XML.

Comment: To get your XML to display, you need to format it as code. I've done this for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @XMLDATA.modify(' insert <Country>IND</Country> as last into (Address[1]) ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update Employee set Address.modify('insert  <Country>IND</Country>
 as last into (/Address)[1]')
```